# Geometry Nodes: How to access data-block properties?

Tags: geometry-nodes

It's a long shot, but is there any way at all to directly access properties stored in vertices/control points data-blocks? There's stuff that doesn't show up in the spreadsheet that I'd love to be able to manipulate, like `weight_softbody` in curves (`bpy.data.curves["curveID"].splines[index].points[index].weight_softbody`). I'm specially interested in being able to access custom properties.

Please note that I know how to access *accessible* properties like `nurbs_weight` by setting those in a **Named Attribute** node.

Comment: Hello ! Just to be clear, you're looking into doing that only within the context of geometry nodes, not with the help of the python scripting API ?

Comment: @Gorgious As long it also works for curve-type objects, I'm desperate to the point I could turn to python, hah. I have this GN tree reading properties of each spline in a curve object to do stuff, and right now I've been stuffing this data in the Nurbs Weight/Radius/Tilt of the first N control points of the splines because these are all I can access from GN on-the-fly. Curves don't have `object[ID].data.attributes` to make custom data accessible to GN.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the solution I was looking for, but it's *a* solution. For now I won't mark it as the accepted answer in case someone has a better method or GN gets the updates needed to avoid this workaround.

## How to read and edit custom Attributes in Edit Mode

I wanted to access all data, including custom data, of curves. The easiest way is to use custom named attributes + python to interact with these attributes in edit mode. You can set it to pull information directly from the object data or create and work with entirely new attributes.

[image: editable attributes proof of concept]

Despite its simplicity, this proof of concept shows how editable custom attributes open up the chance of doing *anything* with your geometry. IE, I'm working an a hair system with many per control points settings.

This approach works not only for "curves" but also meshes.

#### Requirements

Blender 3.2 **alpha** (circa 2022-03-22) must be used for this due its functional support for curves *Named Attributes*. The most recent 3.2 and 3.3 builds (2022-05-31) can't be used because named attributes aren't working for some curve attributes.

#### Fake Curves

Turning a mesh into a default-looking NURBS curve is easy.

[image: Mesh line to curve]

You'll want to add a check for splines with fewer than 5 points, or these will disappear when converted to NURBS.

[image: nurbs_order check]

#### Editable Attributes

Custom attributes are accessible from meshes' **Object Data Properties** panel.

[image: mesh attributes]

You can either write a python snippet to check if they exist, creating and populating with defaults if not, or add them manually and run something on the command line.

In this example **misc_data** should be tied to each control point (point domain) while **profile** and **custom_res** are tied to all points in their splines (splines domain). Because meshes don't have native support for the spline domain you'll need to reassign them after converting to curve.

[image: points to spline domain]

After preparing the attributes, you can let them do their thing.

[image: editable attributes effects]

The full node tree:

[image: full node tree]

This takes care of the geometry nodes functionality part.

#### Making Attributes interactive in Edit Mode with Python

Attribute data disappears when entering in edit mode. Try it out in the console, `bpy.context.active_object.data.attributes['ATTRNAME'].data[0].value` in Object and Edit modes. It's weird and annoying. But there's a workaround, bmesh.

The next issue to be solved is getting these attributes to display and get altered in a viewport panel. I used a custom prop collection to temporarily store the values being displayed in the panel fields, with a setter function to update the real attributes and he viewport.

Here's the full snippet with comments. It's rushed and sloppy but gets the idea across.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import numpy as np

from bpy.types import (
    Operator,
    Panel,
    PropertyGroup,
)
from bpy.props import (
    EnumProperty,
    BoolProperty,
    StringProperty,
    IntProperty,
    CollectionProperty,
    FloatProperty,
    FloatVectorProperty,
    PointerProperty,
)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Misc functions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Tag object for vireport update when Attributes are changed
def refresh_gn(obj):
    obj.update_tag()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Props
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Attributes meta information
CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES = {
    "misc_data": {"prop_type": "float", "domain": "point"},
    "custom_res": {"prop_type": "int", "domain": "spline"},
    "profile": {"prop_type": "int", "domain": "spline"},
}

class SplineAttributesPanelProperties(PropertyGroup):
    # Temporarily store data in custom props to display and edit in 3D view panel
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        bpy.types.Object.curve_attributes = PointerProperty(
                name="Custom Curve Attributes",
                description="Support for custom curve named attributes",
                type=cls,
            )
        
        # Sub props
        cls.misc_data = FloatProperty(
                name="Keep Point",
                description="Set to 0 to remove this point from curve",
                update=update_attr("misc_data"),
                get=get_attr("misc_data"),
                set=set_attr("misc_data"),
                min=0,
            )
        
        cls.custom_res = IntProperty(
                name="Spline Resolution",
                description="Resampling point count and resultion of active spline",
                update=update_attr("custom_res"),
                get=get_attr("custom_res"),
                set=set_attr("custom_res"),
                min=2,
                max=1000,
            )
        
        cls.profile = IntProperty(
                name="Spline Profile ID",
                description="Index of geometry used as profile for this curve",
                update=update_attr("profile"),
                get=get_attr("profile"),
                set=set_attr("profile"),
                min=0,
                max=3,  # Ideally, write code to pull max from geo nodes Collection input
            )

    # Clear when unregistering
    @classmethod
    def unregister(cls):
        del bpy.types.Object.curve_attributes
        #
        del cls.misc_data
        del cls.custom_res
        del cls.profile

## ---------------------------------------------
## Getter, Setter, Updater

## The updater is called every time the user edits something, and when they hover trhe prop too
# Wrapper to avoid writing lambdas in every prop declaration
def update_attr(attr):
    # Retrieve self, context, then add 'attr' parameter
    f = eval("lambda s, c: update_attr_exec(s, c, '%s')" % (attr))
    return f
   
# Real Update Function
def update_attr_exec(self, context, attr):
    # Retrieve value from temp prop
    val = getattr(self, attr)
    # Get meta information
    meta = CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES[attr]
    
    obd = context.active_object.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obd)
    # Get selected vertices
    verts = np.array(bm.verts)
    selected = np.frompyfunc(lambda a: a.select, 1, 1)
    sel = selected(verts).astype(bool)
    v = [s.index for s in verts[sel]]
    
    # First vertex in selection (extra code needed to support vertex multiselection)
    v0 = bm.verts[v[0]]

    # Pull the correct type of layer data by checking the metadata
    attr_layer = eval("bm.verts.layers.%s[attr]" % (meta['prop_type']))  # I'm so lazy
    
    # Set attribute of first vertice in selection to value of temp prop
    v0[attr_layer] = val
    
    # If it's a spline domain, find linked vertices and set them too
    if meta["domain"] == "spline":
        # Retrieve list of id: (vert prop) of linked vertices
        linked_verts = get_linked_verts({v[0]: v0}, {})
        
        # Set attribute for them too
        for idx in linked_verts:
            bm.verts[idx][attr_layer] = val
    
    # Update viewport with new attributes
    refresh_gn(context.active_object)

def get_linked_verts(vs, l, vlen=0):
    t = {}  # Temp list for recursion

    for idx in vs:
        for e in vs[idx].link_edges:
            v = e.other_vert(vs[idx])
            l[v.index] = v # Add to vertices list
            t[v.index] = v # Add to temp list

    nlen = len(l) # update vertices count
    
    if nlen != vlen: # Still finding new vertices
        return get_linked_verts(t, l, nlen)  # Keep counting
    else:
        return l  # Reached the end!

## Getter is called when the prop value is displayed in the UI
# Wrapper to avoid writing lambdas in every prop declaration
def get_attr(attr):
    # Retrieve self, then add 'attr' parameter
    f = eval("lambda s: get_attr_exec(s, '%s')" % (attr))
    return f
    
def get_attr_exec(self, attr):
    # Get meta information
    meta = CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES[attr]    
    
    obd = bpy.context.active_object.data # lazy
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obd)
    # Find selection...
    verts = np.array(bm.verts)
    selected = np.frompyfunc(lambda a: a.select, 1, 1)
    sel = selected(verts).astype(bool)
    v = [s.index for s in verts[sel]]

    attr_layer = eval("bm.verts.layers.%s[attr]" % (meta['prop_type']))  # I'm so lazy
    
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table() # Needed sometimes
    
    # Display value of equivalent attribute of first vertice in selection
    return bm.verts[v[0]][attr_layer]

## Setter is required so the prop isn't read-only. It's caled when the user accepts the changes made
# These functions pretty much copy the updater logic
def set_attr(attr):
    # Retrieve self, value, then add 'attr' parameter
    f = eval("lambda s, v: set_attr_exec(s, v, '%s')" % (attr))
    return f
    
def set_attr_exec(self, value, attr):    
    self[attr] = value
    
    meta = CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES[attr]
    
    obd = bpy.context.active_object.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obd)
    # Find selection...
    verts = np.array(bm.verts)
    selected = np.frompyfunc(lambda a: a.select, 1, 1)
    sel = selected(verts).astype(bool)
    v = [s.index for s in verts[sel]]
    v0 = bm.verts[v[0]]

    attr_layer = eval("bm.verts.layers.%s[attr]" % (meta['prop_type']))  # I'm so lazy
    
    # Set attribute of first vertice in selection to value of temp prop
    v0[attr_layer] = value
    
    # If it's a spline domain, find linked vertices and set them too
    if meta["domain"] == "spline":
    
        linked_verts = get_linked_verts({v[0]: v0}, {})
        for idx in linked_verts:
            bm.verts[idx][attr_layer] = value


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    User interface
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

## Base properties of panel
class EA_props_panel:
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_category = "GN Editable Attributes"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

## Editable Attributes Panel
class PANEL_PT_Editable_Attributes(EA_props_panel, Panel):  
    bl_label = "Active Spline Attributes"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_activeSplineAttributes"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode in {'EDIT_MESH'}
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        oba = context.active_object.curve_attributes       

        col = layout.column()
        col.use_property_split = True
        col.use_property_decorate = False
        col.prop(oba, "custom_res", text="Spline Res")  # Custom Resolution attr
        col.prop(oba, "profile", text="Profile ID")  # Curve Profile attr
        col.separator()
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.alignment = 'RIGHT'
        col.label(text='Selected Control Point')
        col.alignment = 'EXPAND'
        box = col.box()
        row = box.row()
        col = box.column()
        col.prop(oba, "misc_data")  # Float attr
        row = box.row()


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Register
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASSES = [
    SplineAttributesPanelProperties,
    PANEL_PT_Editable_Attributes,
]

def register():
    for cls in CLASSES:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    # Tag obj for update when attr changes
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(refresh_gn)

def unregister():
    for cls in CLASSES:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.remove(refresh_gn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

That's it. It's an absurd workaround, but hey, if it works...